# How to prove this binary operations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(G, ∗)$ be a group and $a,b \in G$.

Show that if $(a∗b)∗(a∗b) = (a∗a)∗(b∗b)$, then $(a∗b)=(b∗a)$.

How can ve prove this? Thanks for your help..

Comment: Do you mean $(a*b)*(a*b)$ on the left hand side?

Comment: Such group with identity $(ab)(cd)=(ac)(bd)$ is called _entropic_ or _medial_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a group, the operation $\cdot$ is associative, hence you have

$(a \cdot b)\cdot(b\cdot a)=a\cdot(b\cdot a)\cdot b$

By your assumption you know it equals

$(a \cdot a) \cdot ( b \cdot b)= a \cdot (a \cdot b) \cdot b$

Then you have

$a\cdot(b\cdot a)\cdot b = a \cdot (a \cdot b) \cdot b$

Since it is a group, there are inverse $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$. You multiply the equation on the left by $a^{-1}$ and on the right by $b^{-1}$ and you get the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are given
$$abab = aabb$$
Premultiply by $a^{-1}$, to get
$$bab = abb$$
Post multiply by $b^{-1}$, to get
$$ba = ab$$

Comment: Well, then (a∗b)∗(a∗b) means aabb, right?

Comment: @AYARcom Yes, a group by definition has the operation to be associative and hence the brackets can be removed.